# What are these gall like growths on my spuds?

Tags: diseases, potatoes

I noticed a volunteer potato plant in the garden a month or so ago which I thought was cool. It's just now at the tail end of winter in the southern hemisphere.

Today I noticed that it had gall like growths where lateral stem branches occur, and where you'd expect to see an axillary bud.  They don't look like tubers so what are they?

[image: enter link description here]
[image: enter link description here]
[image: enter link description here]

Comment: I looked up pests and diseases, and didnt find this gall. So probably not a big problem. A locally produced resource for you is https://potatoesnz.co.nz/?mdocs-file=9982

Comment: I still haven't found out more, and dont know any potato farmers any more. Please let us know if you find out.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to let it grow and see what happens.